# How to use neptune-export

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

Can someone please list out a detailed stepwise process to export data from Neptune to S3(or local storage) in form of CSV.
I followed the doc(which seems to be the only resource available online), but it is not very clear.
TIA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Neptune Export tool has many options that can be used to configure an export of both property graph and RDF data. The overall syntax of the command (if invoked via the command line) is:

```
NAME
        neptune-export.sh export-pg - Export property graph from Neptune to CSV
        or JSON.

SYNOPSIS
        neptune-export.sh export-pg
                [ --alb-endpoint <applicationLoadBalancerEndpoint> ]
                [ --approx-edge-count <approxEdgeCount> ]
                [ --approx-node-count <approxNodeCount> ]
                [ {-b | --batch-size} <batchSize> ]
                [ {-c | --config-file | --filter-config-file} <configFile> ]
                [ --clone-cluster ]
                [ --clone-cluster-instance-type <cloneClusterInstanceType> ]
                [ --clone-cluster-replica-count <replicaCount> ]
                [ {--cluster-id | --cluster | --clusterid} <clusterId> ]
                [ {-cn | --concurrency} <concurrency> ]
                [ {--config | --filter} <configJson> ] {-d | --dir} <directory>
                [ --disable-ssl ] [ {-e | --endpoint} <endpoint>... ]
                [ --edge-label-strategy <edgeLabelStrategy> ]
                [ {-el | --edge-label} <edgeLabels>... ]
                [ --escape-csv-headers ] [ --escape-newline ]
                [ --exclude-type-definitions ] [ --export-id <exportId> ]
                [ --format <format> ] [ --janus ]
                [ --lb-port <loadBalancerPort> ] [ --limit <limit> ]
                [ --log-level <log level> ]
                [ --max-content-length <maxContentLength> ] [ --merge-files ]
                [ --multi-value-separator <multiValueSeparator> ]
                [ {-nl | --node-label} <nodeLabels>... ]
                [ --nlb-endpoint <networkLoadBalancerEndpoint> ]
                [ {-o | --output} <output> ] [ {-p | --port} <port> ]
                [ --partition-directories <partitionDirectories> ]
                [ --per-label-directories ] [ --profile <profiles>... ]
                [ {-r | --range | --range-size} <rangeSize> ]
                [ {--region | --stream-region} <region> ]
                [ {-s | --scope} <scope> ] [ --serializer <serializer> ]
                [ --skip <skip> ]
                [ --stream-large-record-strategy <largeStreamRecordHandlingStrategy> ]
                [ --stream-name <streamName> ] [ --strict-cardinality ]
                [ {-t | --tag} <tag> ] [ --token-prefix <tokenPrefix> ]
                [ --tokens-only <tokensOnly> ] [ --use-iam-auth ] [ --use-ssl ]
```

There are detailed instructions at the GitHub page for the tool that describe the alternative ways to export data. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-export

If you still have questions I suggest making edits to the original question to clarify the precise challenges you have encountered.